# DbProviderFactory implementation for MongoDB

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, .net-core

Does an implementation of `DbProviderFactory` in .Net Core exist for MongoDB?

Comment: I've no seen one, but it seems like the wrong abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kevin. Can you explain more about what you mean by it being the wrong abstraction? Maybe i'm going down the wrong route?

Comment: DbCommand, DbConnection, DbDataAdapter etc.. are all based around relational SQL database - See the description of DbCommand https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: … and you do not use SQL to work with MongoDB. See https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp for a typesafe way to work with MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks! So i am using DbProviderFactory as a way to access multiple database types generically. Would there be an equivalent for NoSQL databases so that i can support MongoDB, Cassandra, etc.?

Comment: You'd have to create your own abstraction which maps to what you're storing/querying then implement this for each of your data stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbProviderFactory` is for creating database providers for Relational SQL databases, seeing as MongoDB is a document database it doesn't really fit into the model.

If you need to be database agnostic I'd personally create your own abstraction layer on what you're doing with your data and then implement each of our database providers.

For example:

```cs
interface IMyDataStore
{
    List<Data> GetAllData();
    UpdateField1(string field1);
}

class MongoMyDataStore : IMyDataStore
{
    // MonogDb stuff
}

class DbProviderDataStore : IMyDataStore
{
    // Things that use DbProvider
}
```